# What is the simplest Spring (3) application that could possibly work?

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring 3 and trying to create the most basic application that could possibly work.

This is what I have so far:

**HeyDude.java**

```
package test;                                                                      

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;                               
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;                  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;                    
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;                    

@Controller                                                                     
public class HeyDude {                                                          

    @RequestMapping("/hello")                                                   
    public @ResponseBody String hello () {                                      
        return "Such cool. Many awesome.";                                      
    }                                                                           
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xsi:schemalocation="http:/java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

    <display-name>Spring test for awesome!</display-name>                       
    <servlet>                                                                   
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>                                     
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>                                                                  

    <servlet-mapping>                                                           
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>                                     
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>                                       
    </servlet-mapping>                                                          
<!--                                                                            
-->                                                                             
</web-app>
```

**build.xml**

```
<property name="name" value="api"/>                                         
<property name="lib.dir" value="${name}/WEB-INF/lib"/>                      
<property name="build.dir" value="${name}/WEB-INF/classes"/> 

<target name="testbuild" description="Compile main source tree java files"> 
    <mkdir dir="${lib.dir}"/>                                                  
    <copy todir="${lib.dir}" preservelastmodified="true">                      
        <fileset dir="/usr/share/tomcat7/lib/">                                
            <include name="servlet-api.jar"/>                                  
        </fileset>                                                             
        <fileset dir="/path/to/other/libs">
            <include name="spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar" />                   
            <include name="spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar" />                    
            <include name="spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar" />                
            <include name="spring-servlet-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar" />                
        </fileset>                                                             
    </copy>                                                                    
    <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.6"                                 
        includeantruntime="false"                                              
        target="1.6" debug="true"                                              
        deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">               
        <src path="${build.dir}/test"/>                                        
        <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>                               
    </javac>                                                                
</target>

<target name="testwar" depends="testbuild" description="Build a WAR">          
    <war basedir="api/" warfile="my-test.war">                         
        <exclude name="${build-dir}" />                                     
        <exclude name="downloads/*" />                                      
    </war>                                                                  
</target>
```

And yet, I still get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

What do I have to do to get this to work, and why? Alternatively, if there is an even simpler app I could create, I'd love to see it!

Comment: is ant + spring 3 a constraint, or you can switch to maven + spring 4? in the latter case, spring-boot is an awesome tooling to get you started

Comment: More or less a constraint. Plus in my experience Maven is *more* complicated, not less (though it does hide some of the complexity. I guess. I never was able to get it to actually work, heh.)

Comment: @WayneWerner So you think Maven makes things complicated and yet your non maven project seems to show an error related to a missing dependency.

Comment: When I use the word complicated I guess I mean that I don't understand how it works or what it's doing. I feel like I'm flailing wildly. With what I'm **trying** to do I still feel like I'm flailing wildly because I cannot for the life of me find a basic example that says, "In order to create a spring app you need X, Y, Z". Every example I've seen says, "From Eclipse..." - sure, it's fine to use the tools, but I am trying to understand how they're supposed to work. Right now I obviously don't understand how Spring works - and that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: maven does enforce a strict build lifecycle making builds homogeneous; it does not make your life easier, but it achieves the same for the build engineers... using a script based build like ant or newer DSL based build tools make the build configuration become code; as such being code, it then needs maintenance level of any other code, and any code is much more painful to maintain than xml configuration of an enforced lifecycle.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to try Spring 4? Because if you do want to, you can try Spring Boot which will vastly reduce the amount of configuration you need to get setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M. Deinum's answer led me to what I was looking for:

Add these dependencies to the **build.xml**

```
            <include name="spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar" />                
            <include name="spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar" />                 
            <include name="spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar" />             
            <include name="spring-context-support-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar" />     
            <include name="spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar" />              
            <include name="spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar" />               
            <include name="org_apache_commons_logging.jar" />               
            <include name="spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar" />
```

I changed up my **web.xml**

```
<display-name>Spring test for awesome!</display-name>                       
<servlet>                                                                   
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>                                     
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>                                    
</servlet>                                                                  

<servlet-mapping>                                                           
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>                                     
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>                                           
</servlet-mapping>
```

With the correct dependencies, it exposed the necessity for **spring-servlet.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                             
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"                         
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                          
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"                           
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"                  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd                   


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context                                      


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">             

    <context:component-scan base-package="test" />                                 
</beans>
```

**HeyDude.java** now looks like this:

```
@Controller                                                                        
public class HeyDude {                                                             

    @RequestMapping("/")                                                           
    public @ResponseBody String hello () {                                         
        return "Such cool. Many awesome.";                                         
    }                                                                              

}
```

So Spring has several requirements (including Apache commons logging). Spring also requires a `spring-servlet.xml` which probably needs that `context:component-scan` element in it (vs somewhere else. It's definitely required)

This is the simplest Spring app that I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you are missing quite some dependencies (**spring-beans**, **spring-context-supprt** and probably **spring-expression**) and you have non-existing dependencies (**spring-servlet**, which probably must be **spring-webmvc**).

Next your `@Controller` is wrong it currently maps to `/hello` which will lead to a URL `/hello/hello` which will never be touched by the `DispatcherServlet` as it is mapped to `/hello` and not `/hello/*` however I expect you want it to map to `/hello` so map your servlet to `/` or `/*`

Finally I would strongly recommend you start to look at Maven (or Gradle) again. You don't want to be searching the internet for which jars you need to include into your project. If you really want to keep using ant at least look into [Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/) for dependency management.

For maven the following would be enough (and is roughly a translation of your `build.xml` file).

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Provided Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This will download all necesarry dependencies and will create a war file, when you do `mvn package`.